# What is difference between keras.Model and keras.engine.training.Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, pruning

I have been trying to prune a keras model post-training.
while doing that, I get model type as NoneType returned. While going into the source code of Pruning API, it says the model has to be type keras.Model, but what I am passing has the type keras.engine.training.Model

So, is there is any differnece among both?

Answer (score 1):

Both are the exact same class:

```
>>> import keras
>>> keras.models.Model
<class 'keras.engine.training.Model'>
>>> keras.Model
<class 'keras.engine.training.Model'>
```